# flutter: Is it possible to use conditional statements in pageview?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create a function that automatically moves to the next page when a certain condition is met using 'pageview'.
For example, if a=0 becomes a=1, it should automatically advance to the next page.
Instead of going to the next page by clicking a button in the pageview, is it possible to automatically go to the next page using a conditional statement?

```
             Expanded(

            child:
                
            PageView.builder(
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              controller: _questionController.pageController,
              onPageChanged: _questionController.updateTheQnNum,
              itemCount: _questionController.questions.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => QuestionCard(
                question: _questionController.questions[index],
                myanswer: testtext,
              ),
            )
          ),
```

This is part of my code. When a=1, it should advance to the next page, otherwise it should keep the current page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two methods that can help you achieve it.

[animateToPage](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageController/animateToPage.html)

```
_questionController.pageController.animateToPage(pageIndex);
```

or

[jumpToPage](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageController/jumpToPage.html)

```
_questionController.pageController.jumpToPage(pageIndex);
```

As the name suggests `animateToPage` will animate the transition from Page A to Page B where `jumpToPage` won't animate.

Make sure `pageIndex` is within the range.